# Proving function is integrable (Darboux integral)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have functions $f, g, h$ and they are all definite in $[a,b]$. I also know that 
$$f(x)\leq g(x) \leq h(x)\quad \forall x \in [a,b];$$
and that $f$, $h$ are integrable in $[a,b]$ and
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b}h(x) dx =\colon I.$$
So I need to prove that $g(x)$ is integrable (Darboux) in $[a,b]$ and that $\int_{a}^{b}g(x) dx=I.$
How to do this? It seems simple but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/148510).

Comment: Hint: For any partition $P$, $L(P,f) \leqslant L(P,g) \leqslant U(P,g) \leqslant U(P,h)$ and $L(P,g) \leqslant \underline{\int_a}^b g \leqslant \overline{\int_a^b}g \leqslant U(P,g)$